# resetting variables in php to display in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, database, variables, reset

I'm trying to get some values off a DB and then putting those values into javascript variables. I managed to do just that, the problem I'm having is when the values in the DB change the values of the variables don't. I figured the problem lies within my PHP, but I cant find it. Can you guys help me?

here's my code:

### PHP

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['u_name'])){
$_SESSION['u_name'] = '';
}

mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "") or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('raffleiz_Main')or die ("cannot select DB :(");

$signups = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Rafflez_info`") or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
$row = mysql_num_rows($signups);

    //pull all of the data and store it
    for($p = 0; $p < $row; $p++){
        $participants[$p] = mysql_result($signups, $p, "#_participants");
    };
        for($a = 0; $a < $row; $a++){
        $max_participants[$a] = mysql_result($signups, $a, "max_participants");
    };

?>
```

### and my javascript function:

```
function progress(){

    var signups = "<?php echo $participants[0]; ?>";
    var maxP = "<?php echo $max_participants[0]; ?>";

    alert (signups);
    alert (maxP);

    var pSignup = signups / maxP;

    alert (pSignup);

    var total = 550 * pSignup;

    var theImg = document.getElementById('progress');
    theImg.width = total;

    alert (total);

};
```

I put the "alert" command there so that I could see the change in the values. right now the values don't change no matter what I change them to in the DB.

Comment: You're reading the same index (`0`) every time...

Comment: Why do you `SELECT` *everything* from the database to then `echo` only the first one?

Comment: The php just outputs static code. Your code doesn't talk to the db at all. You have to refresh the page to see the changes.

Comment: I select everything because there will be more entries down the line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call your php page and ask it if values are changes. You can easily use jQuery AJAX to achieve that. Use JSON for easier data transfer.  If you want to check if values are changes every 3 seconds for example you can do this:

```
var interval = window.setInterval(function(){
  jQuery.ajax({
   url: 'your php file address',
   success: function(data){
      progress(data)
   }
  });
}, 3000);
```

You will need to change you `proccess` and php code. This is just to give you the idea.

Comment: Thanks, I got a long way to go in Ajax, I'm going through the tutorial remibreton linked.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a [server-side language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting), meaning that when it served the script from the server to the client, there is no going back.

JavaScript is a [client-side language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-side_scripting), thus can receive values from a server-side language such as PHP. The values received are then client-side only, a copy if you will.

You can use the [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) API to request a script from a server, updating the local client-side values.

I recommend using the [jQuery `$.ajax` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to easily achieve that.

Here's a [nice tutorial from Nettuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/) to get your started.